# Unica "Treatment Code" into and out of ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, data-export, campaign, dataextensions

We're installing UNICA and part of the installation will be the creation of "Treatment Codes" which identify what email a recipient received, and also connects any activity (Clicks, Opens) back to the email too.

We can easily import the Treatment Code and the Customer ID into ET via a Data Extension, but how can we link that data back when we receive the aggregate CLICKS, OPENS, BOUNCES, etc back?

There's no option to pull the Data Extension data out in an automated way, but I really doubt we're the first organization trying to do this.

Any and all help would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: Follow-up question:  Has anyone considered using the SUBSCRIBER KEY as the value for my predicament?  The only downfall I can think of is the unsubscribe functionality -- how does an unsubscribe work if the email address appears many times because there are many subscriber keys?

The hope would be that the email address would be unsubscribed from all email, and not just the one tied to the unique subscriber key.

Comment: Unsub would only apply to subscriber key. You can probably create an automation to unsub all matching email addresses to those unsubscribed in system though if needed to cover for this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if the user replies "Unsubscribe" or clicks the ET-generated link to unsubscribe, only the Subscriber Key is unsubscribed.  If we create a new Subscriber Key each day, via an import to a Data Extension, then the user would be unsubscribing only from that one DE, and might get an email the following day, no?

Comment: Yes - you would have to build a custom suppression list or filter to prevent them from being sent to.

Comment: unfortunately, it seems my idea won't work because we would need to migrate our data to the new schema... ugh, back to the drawing board :(